# PySpark : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to join two tables and limit 1 in joined table in pyspark:

```
df = spark.sql("""
select 
   table_a.*, table_b.*
from 
   table_a 
left join
   table_b
on
   table_a.id = table_b.fk_a_id
and 
   table_b.id = (select max(id) from table_b where fk_a_id = table_a.id)
""")
df.count()
```

After running the code, I will get an error as

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found: table_b
```

The code will run correctly without the line with `and`, which is

```
df = spark.sql("""
select 
   table_a.*, table_b.*
from 
   table_a 
left join
   table_b
on
   table_a.id = table_b.fk_a_id
""")
df.count()
```

Any suggestions about what happened? If I did it in a wrong way, if there are any methods I can take to achieve the same thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spark follows the Hive SQL syntax and it doesn't support [subqueries for joins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries)

So you can rewrite your query like this:

```sql
select 
   table_a.*, table_b.*
from 
   table_a 
left join
   table_b
on
   table_a.id = table_b.fk_a_id
where 
   table_b.id = (select max(id) from table_b where fk_a_id in (select id from table_a))
```

or

```sql
select 
   table_a.*, t_b.*
from 
   table_a 
left join
   (
   select * from table_b
    where id = (select max(id) from table_b where fk_a_id in (select id from table_a)
   ) as t_b
on
   table_a.id = t_b.fk_a_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that I need to learn more about spark sql.

Comment: @lushuming You can also read this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html) for spark 3
There are some new experimental properties to make spark sql ANSI compliant